# A set theory problem related to Russell's paradox

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set， $f\colon X \to P(X)$ a map, where $P(X)$ is the power set of $X$. If $$
Z =\{x \in  X: x \not\in f(x) \} $$ 
 then which one is right?

A. $Z$ is empty
B. $Z$ isn't empty
C. $Z=X$ 
D. $Z$ doesn't belong to $P(X)$ 
E. $Z$'s complement belongs to $P(X)$

I think it's related to Russell's paradox, but still don't know how to work this out.

Comment: All except one of these *can* be true; only one of them is *always* true. Also, this is not so much related to Russel's paradox as it is to Cantor's theorem.

Comment: Take them one at a time. Four of them will have counterexamples. ***VERY*** simple counterexamples, which you can find, if yoiu can bother yourself to think about it. Take B: "$Z$ isn;t empty." To refute B, all you have to do is find an example where $Z$ is empty. Well, what if we define $f(x)=\emptyset$ for all $x\in X$? Or for that matter, what if we just take $X=\emptyset$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem statement says $f$ is a **map**, not a surjective map. So such a map exists. That means $Z$ exists too, and by extension, $X\setminus Z$ exists, and belongs to $P(X)$.
Counterexamples to the other options (valid when $X$ is suitably chosen): A) Define $f: X \to P(X)$ by $f(x)=X \setminus \{x\}$. B) Define $f: X \to P(X)$ by $f(x)=\{x\}$. C) See (B). D) Since $Z$ is a subset of $X$, whether empty or nonempty, it is always in $P(X)$.

Russell's Paradox is related if one assumes that $f$ is a surjective map, in which case it can be shown that such an $f$ does not exist, since in that case, $f(z)=Z$ for some $z\in X$, then if $z\in Z$, then $Z$ cannot be the set of all $x$ which are not in $X$, and if $z \notin Z$, then by the construction of $Z$, it must contain $z$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the map $f$. The crucial point is that $Z$ is not in the image of $f$ so $f$ is not onto whatever $f$ is.

consider eg when $f$ maps everything to the empty set, and $f$ maps everything to $X$, and also when $f(x) = \{ x\}.$

The connection with Russell's paradox is tenuous -- there is no paradox here.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it looks a lot like Russell's paradox, but the most important part is missing - the surjectivity of $f$. That's critical to the paradox, so no paradox occurs here. Which means that thinking about Russell's paradox is completely irrelevant.

Think about it in terms of the definitions involved. $\mathscr{P}(X)$ is the set of subsets of $X$; $f$ is a map assigning a subset of $X$ to each member of $X$. If that were all you knew, and you'd never heard of Russell's paradox, which of these would seem likely to be true? For example, if (A) were correct, it would have to be that *every single* assignment sends *every single* point to a set not containing it. That there is *no way* to send, for example, $0$ to a set containing $0$. Does that seem plausible? Think about the rest of them similarly.